How can I loop through the returned data from a http.get() angular call?
So getallaccounts() calls and returns from a service via http.get('address')...I'm getting that RES has no length.. I am getting back an array...confused....
  ngOnInit() {
    this.requestService.getAllAccounts().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        //var jsonres = res.json();
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < res[i].passwords.length; j++) {
            let theTime = new Date(res[i].passwords[j].expiryDate).getTime();
            let theNow = new Date().getTime();
            let difference = theTime - theNow;
            if (difference <= 2592000) {
              if (difference <= 0) {
                res[i].passwords[j].classcolor = "red";
              } else {
                res[i].passwords[j].classcolor = "yellow";

In the console I console.log out the RES and see

(113) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},{…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99] 0 :  {id: 91, title: 'People Soft',
description: 'People Soft', isActive: 'Y', isRetired: 'N', …} 1 :
{id: 92, title: 'PGP Universal Server Administrator', description:
'PGP Universal Server Administrator', isActive: 'Y', isRetired: 'Y',
…}


Can you share the response in JSON snippet?

@YongShun updated..

Hmmm, it's quite odd. In your getAllAccounts method, have you do any specific action, such as specifying the response type, or any RxJS operators to transform the data? So now your question is you are unable to iterate the array in subscribe method?

yup unable to iterate over the subscribed object...but when I return it to the front end via the template..
this.accounts = res
I can iterate through it in the front end no problem..

Not sure, probably do you specify the return type for getAllAccounts method with any[]? And specify the res type to any[]: `this.requestService.getAllAccounts().subscribe((res: any[]) => { ... });

@BostonMacOSX Please share the full code inside the subscribe

Please check your response is array console.log(Array.isArray(res))

I will add the code this morning...sorry got late last night.

@JaskaranSingh console.log(Array.isArray(res)); is coming back in the console as true..

Please check above for solution @JaskaranSingh

I had to cast the Observable to Array and the loop and the push to the front end took fine....
for (let i = 0; i < (res as Array<Object>).length; i++) {

